# Magento 1 - Load js in footer

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, layout, template

```
<reference name="footer">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_js</type>
        <file>js/fabric/tool/controller_tool.js</file>
    </action>
</reference>
```

I used above code to load js in footer. But Magento throws error Like

> Invalid method Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer::addItem(Array (
>       [0] => skin_js
>       [1] => js/fabric/tool/controller_tool.js ) )

I need to load js in footer. How To overcome this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently Magento footer block has not been designed to add javascripts.

I tried a while ago refactoring Magento and the footer block to load every JS in the footer instead of the header but the way the JS call are called inside the templates makes it very hard to get this working.

My suggestion to fix your issue is to update your layout like this:

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="core/template" name="controller_tool_javascript" template="fabric/tool/controller_tool_js.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Create a `fabric/tool/controller_tool_js.phtml` file in your template folder with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/fabric/tool/controller_tool.js') ?>"></script>
```

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 12):

The footer doesn't have these functionalities, only the `head` does as this block is of type `page/html_head` which holds these methods.

You can achieve this by putting the JS `<script src=...></script>` tag inside a template (`.phtml` file) and include that as a `core/template` block:

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="core/template" name="fabric_controller_tool_js" template="fabric/controller_tool_js.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Also you could add it through a `core/text` block:

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="core/text" name="fabric_controller_tool_js">
         <action method="setText">
             <text><![CDATA[<script src="/js/fabric/tool/controller_tool.js"></script>]]></text>
         </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just want tell you why `addItem` not work in `reference name="footer"`

When you use `reference name="footer"` then it will call this block

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
```

which you will find in `page.xml` in your theme.

so it  mean it will check `addItem` method/function in that block class or in their parent class, but this function is not there,   that's why it will not work and it will throw  exception.

Answer (score 2):

`<reference name="footer">` does not work in my case.
I've found more appropriate block for js called `js`:

```
<reference name="js">
    <block type="core/text" name="fabric_controller_tool_js">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<script src="/js/fabric/tool/controller_tool.js"></script>]]></text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Or through separate template. path: design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/js.phtml:

```
<reference name="js">
    <block type="core/template" name="fabric_controller_tool_js" template="sales/order/js.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a different method to achieve what you may be seeking to accomplish. Instead of twisting magento's arm, I just load my script in the head, but set a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener (not supported in ie8) to which performs my tasks.

### app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/namespace_module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.0.1">
  <default>
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs">
        <script>NameSpace/Module/entry.js</script>
      </action>
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

### app/code/community/NameSpace/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <NameSpace_Module>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </NameSpace_Module>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <module>
          <file>namespace_module.xml</file>
        </module>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

### js/NameSpace/Module/entry.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  // do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add new block in page.xml

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
    <block type="page/html_head" name="footerjscss" as="footerjscss" after="-" template="page/html/footerjscss.phtml"/>
</block>
```

then add JS & CSS files in any layout.xml

```
<reference name="footerjscss">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/slideshow.js</name></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/madisonisland.css</name><params/><if/></action>
</reference>
```

Create .phtml file in page/html/footerjscss.phtml and add following

```
<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
```

Now call block in page template “3columns.phtml” and etc. you will need to output this block before  tag:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
```

Refer code here: http://blog.rahuldadhich.com/magento-load-css-js-footer/